# Sqlite Multiply all values of a single column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let say I have this:

```
id | value
01 | 2
02 | 2
03 | NULL
04 | 4
05 | 3
```

How can I get 48 with a select statement in Sqlite (2*2*4*3) ?

In traditionnal SQL, we use a combination of EXP() SUM() and LOG() but in Sqlite LOG does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only method in SQLite is a recursive CTE.  Let me assume that `id` is sequential:

```
with cte as (
      select id, value as prod, 1 as lev
      from t
      where id = 1
      union all
      select t.id, cte.prod * coalesce(t.value, 1), lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.id = cte.id + 1
    )
select prod
from cte
order by lev desc
limit 1;
```

The normal method in other databases is to use natural logs, sum, and exponentiation.  However, you need a SQLite extension to get these mathematical functions.

If you are going to use an extension, you might as well use one that creates a `product()` aggregation function.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t2MPdsUbEdYHRpGAAFFUVd/0) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: `cte.id` is undefined

Comment: Here is the link if you want to test with your code. But I still get this cte.id undefined
https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5b55ef315dcd2dxjjyenn0u

Comment: Now (after your modification), it makes an infinite loop. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @bobier2 . . . It is fixed.